# A Tree of Tree ADT's: Doesn't make sense

Tags: tree, adt

I've a made a small tree of the tree ADT's and it's raised some issues for me. I made the tree based on information in my course slides.

```
                                      Tree
                                     /   \
                              Binary     Non-Binary
                             /      \                     
                            /        \
              Standard Binary       Search Binary Tree
               /          \
              /            \
            Complete       Proper
```

Problem: A condition of a binary tree is that the left child precedes the right. However, a complete tree is a type of std.binary tree which in turn is a type of binary tree, and this is problematic because a complete tree, like a heap, is left filled and can therefore violate the principle that left child < right child.

[image]

and

[image]

Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Trees are inherently recursive: If you detach the node "Standard Binary" from its "Binary" parent, you have a binary tree with root node "Standard Binary".  No principles violated.

Comment: Why would I detach it though if a standard binary tree IS a type of binary tree? I'm trying to map their actual relationships to one another. I understand what your saying though.

Comment: _A condition of a binary tree is that the left child precedes the right._ There is no rule like this. What do you mean by _precedes_?

Comment: My slide says: "A left child precedes a right child in the ordering of children of a node". So a node will have the smallest child on the left and the biggest child on the right, i guess.

Comment: Can you share the link to the slides?

Comment: No link available, but i edited the post.